# ASP.NET MVC 5 slow response in Chrome, but not in Firefox, IE and Edge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, google-chrome, response

In Firefox, IE and Edge the application has a very fast response time every time I access a page. In Google Chrome after a period of inactivity(let's say one minute) on the site if I try to access a page it is working very slow, about 30 seconds the response time. In other browsers I do not face this problem. I have tried to run incognito the Chrome browser and disable cache from developer tools to check, but the problem is still there. I also tried to publish the application in release mode and set debug on false in web.config. I really need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check how much time your resources are taking to download. This way you'll get an idea which resource is taking maximum time. Also check whether you have any external resource in your page.

Comment: The page has a response time of 1.9 minutes, the type is document and initiator other.

Comment: The connection setup is the following:Queueing 
​
1.93 ms
Stalled 
​
1.9 min
DNS Lookup 
​
0.01 ms
Initial connection 
​
0.32 ms
Request/Response  TIME
Request sent 
​
0.07 ms
Waiting (TTFB) 
​
43.40 ms
Content Download 
​
12.71 ms
Explanation 1.9 min

Comment: The problem is the stalled time is very high. How could I solve this?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206067/understanding-chrome-network-log-stalled-state

Answer (score 0):

seems like something is wrong in your chrome settings. Try these links:

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/a-quick-fix-for-your-slow-chrome-browser/

http://ccm.net/faq/7859-google-chrome-takes-too-long-to-load-a-page

Thanks.