# Measure File Upload Time : Railo

Tags: logging, file-upload, fiddler, railo, time-tracking

I'm using Railo & have a code with cffile ="upload" tag to upload a file to a temp directory on server & then cffile="readbinary" to store the file in a variable & upload the same to the database.

Unfortunately, some users are experiencing latency while uploading the file. In chrome, when I see the network log - F12 developer options, the request is in **Stalled** status for around 100 seconds. Post that, once I start receiving the response back from the server I see the request stats which indicates that the whole request took around 105 seconds to execute.

I believe this is a network related issue since only some users are experiencing it. My question is how do I prove it to the network team as an application developer?

I've tried using cflog tag before & after the cffile tag. The strange thing that happens is Railo doesn't log anything until the file is uploaded to the temp directory on the server. My interpretation is that for those 100 seconds, the file is being sent from my PC, that is, the client to the server and the request is still not completely received by the server. So, it doesn't log anything until the request is completely received by the server. In effect, on the UI screen it takes more than 100 seconds to execute my request and as per the log the entire process took only 2-3 seconds. Weird!!

To confirm this, I went to Railo Admin screen -> Debugging -> Logs to check the total execution time of the request. But it was in vain. It showed 2-3 seconds again.

So, coming back to my question, how do I prove that it's the file upload that is taking so long to execute? Can **Fiddler** help here? If yes, how?

Much Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are they uploading a single file or multiple files? Check this answer regarding the Chrome dev tools and what they mean - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29564247/1636917.

Comment: It's a single file of around 10-20 MB.