# How to set up php-fpm multithreading work?

Tags: php, linux, fpm

php-fpm config ：

```
  pm = dynamic 
  pm.max_children = 50 
  pm.start_servers = 20 
  pm.min_spare_servers = 10
```

and this is nginx config:

```
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

But When I send 50 requests at the same time, it is executed one by one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the grey part of the request in the network log is stalled. If so then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206067/understanding-chrome-network-log-stalled-state is relevant, but the bottom line is it's not a PHP-FPM issue since the request hasn't actually hit PHP-FPM yet when it's in the grey part. If you want to test 50 concurrent requests the browser is probably a bad tool to use

Comment: @apokryfos Thak you,you are correct, ApacheBeam test is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

This could be because of the sessions.

By default php store sessions in files and during request block this file, so next request can be started only after previous is finished.

Try to store sessions in memcache or database.

Comment: This is a very good and probably barely appreciated point. A page making multiple concurrent ajax requests to load various portions can be significantly slowed down due to session locks.

Comment: This is an absolute brilliant answer, that have solved a problem I have had for literally several years! Using CakePHP and a file based session handler, PHP simply locked the session file thus creating a queue of waiting PHP requests if a PHP requests where running for a long time, for example caused by a long running database query.
Simply using the database as the session handler completely solved the issue.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't recommend a regular database (MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL) as a session datastore. These are 10 to 100x slower than memory (Redis or Memcached). Another way, without depending on these (if there is no need to access sessions from multiple hosts in a load balanced inv.) is to store them in TMPFS. See https://eddmann.com/posts/storing-php-sessions-file-caches-in-memory-using-tmpfs/