# Why JS resources are being stalled for a significant amount of time?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, performance, devtools

I am migrating a Java Web application to use Spring Boot. Currently, the problem I have is that the requests for JavaScript resources are being stalled for a significant amount of time and I cannot find the reason for this.
I have a jsp file which references the js files and they are being loaded but take a lot of time in the stalled phase. I use Google Chrome, but tested in Microsoft Edge and the situation is the same there, so the browser is not the problem
[current look on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jcac.png)
[look of more requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyaTy.png)

I tried increasing "server.tomcat.threads.max=500" property, but no change was seen for the js requests and I do not have any idea what should I look for in order to investigate the issue. I haven't made any changes in the front end code, so I assume the problem may arise from the backend but I do not know what to search and look for. Any ideas would be of immense help

[requests from start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjVAi.png)

Comment: Webbrowsers have a limit to how many files can be downloaded simultaneously. If you reach this limit, any other request is stalled until there's "room" for the file to be downloaded. So the important question is: what is happening before all those stalled requests? Can you show a full network log with all the timings?

Comment: Relevant: [Understanding Chrome network log "Stalled" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206067/understanding-chrome-network-log-stalled-state)

Comment: Before stalling the requests only 3 css files are loaded and after that with each request requesting for a js resource the stalling time is getting greater. I am running the application on localhost. What is interesting is that when I run the previous implementation with no Spring Boot, the stalling of the requests is milliseconds. I have uploaded new image with requests from the start. The request which are loading the scripts are progressively slowing down as if they wait for each other

Comment: I can't explain why it worked with a previous implementation without Spring Boot, but from the network log it seems you're making a lot of requests in parallel. Web browsers like Chrome or Edge only handle 6 requests to a single domain in parallel. This seems to match the screenshot you attached (first 6 requests are executed almost at the same time, then the following 6 have a bit more stall time and the following 6 have even more stall time).